# Is there a way to expand this code for user defined number of objects?

Tags: python-3.x, object, simulation, vpython

We were given a homework which required us to simulate the classic mice pursuit problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mice_problem. I have written the code to simulate mice in 3-gon i.e. a triangle. I can also easily add another mice manually to simulate mice on the vertices of a square. This is pretty much enough for the homework but what I'm trying to do to this program is that I would like to create a simulation of n mice where the user has the freedom of choosing any arbitrary n.

My code *(In VPython)*:

```
#instantiating objects

s1 = sphere(pos=vector(0,0,0), radius=0, make_trail='True', trail_color=color.red)
s2 = sphere(pos=vector(2,0,0), radius=0, make_trail='True', trail_color=color.blue)
s3 = sphere(pos=vector(1,sqrt(3),0), radius=0, make_trail='True', trail_color=color.green)

#defining constants

speed = 5
dt = 0.01

#defining driving function

def move_snail(s, dir):
    return s.pos += speed * dt * dir

#setting up animating loop

while True:
    rate(10)

    p1 = s1.pos
    p2 = s2.pos
    p3 = s3.pos

    #defining directions

    dir_1 = hat(p2-p1)
    dir_2 = hat(p3-p2)
    dir_3 = hat(p1-p3)

    #calling function and updating position

    move_snail(s1, dir_1)
    move_snail(s2, dir_2)
    move_snail(s3, dir_3)
```

Comment: Is there some reason that placing *n* items equally around the circumference of a circle wouldn't work for you?

Comment: @pjs haha, sometimes my IQ is 4. Thank you for the comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Another comment is that you could ask the user for "n" and then use a loop to add n sphere objects to a list. Then inside the animation loop you would loop through that list, updating the pos attributes of the n sphere objects.